# iOS app cleaning cache (Swift and Parse)

Tags: ios, swift, caching, parse-platform

I'm testing my app using Parse and the weight of it is just 10mb in my device but as long as I keep testing it, it gets bigger and bigger according to the documents and data storage. My question is: How can I get rid of this data using swift and how will it affect to my app?

Thanks

Comment: Need a little more context on what your app does and how you cache things. Do you use any third-party caching module? If so which one?

Comment: Im using Parse and My app basically upload and show images and texts.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: https://parse.com/questions/clear-app-cache

> You can use clearAllCachedResults:
>
> `[PFQuery clearAllCachedResults];`

In Swift it would be:

`PFQuery.clearAllCachedResults()`

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work… I've been looking for an answer and for what I've found, maybe using the SDWebImage it could be solved. Glad to hear another solution if somebody have a better one.